# GRE Practice Question Incorrect?

Tags: inequality, fractions, word-problem, ratio, gre-exam

This is a sample GRE question. The answer claims that we cannot make an inference due to insufficient information.

> *Compare the following quantities:*
>
> Of the 25 people in Fran’s apartment building, there are 9 residents
>   who use the roof only for tanning and 8 residents who use the roof
>   only for gardening. The roof is only used by tanners and gardeners.
>
> **Quantity A:** The ratio of people who use the roof to total residents
>
> **Quantity B:** 17:25
>
> In this question, we do not know if there is any overlap between
>   tanners and gardeners. How many, if any, residents do both activities?
>   Since we don’t know, the relationship cannot be determined from the
>   information given.

Given that this question specifies **only**, how can the answer imply that there may be an overlap? E.g. If I use the roof for tanning *and* gardening then I do **not** use the the roof *only* for tanning.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that there are 9 people who *only* garden and 8 who *only* tan; that leaves 8 who might do *both* or might do *neither*. If all 8 of the leftover do neither, then the ratio is indeed 17:25 - but if all 8 do both, then the ratio is 25:25. Or if four of them do neither and four do both, the ratio is 21:25. As a matter of fact, for any integer $n$ between $17$ and $25$ inclusive we can come up with a scenario in which the ratio is $n$:25.

Comment: Thanks so much, exactly the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @Reese I agree with your reasoning, but doesn't it then follow that $A\ge B$, i.e., the two quantities *can* be compared?

Comment: @grand_chat But we can't tell whether they're equal; "compare" usually means determining that as well.

Comment: @Reese Hmph, if this is a multiple choice question I'd like to see what the choices were :)

Comment: The possible answers are: A>B, A<B, A=B, Unknown. In this case, the only entirely true answer would be unknown.